# Python: how can I store map between pairs or string arrays and float for fast access?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tuples

I have an array of pairs. Each element of a pair is a list of strings. For each such pair I compute a float value (which represents similarity score between the two lists). What I need is to store it in an object of some type to be able to quickly retrieve a float given the corresponding pair (or 0 if such pair does not exist).

My first thought was to create a dictionary and use a tuple representing a pair as the dictionary key, but since each element of the tuple is a list, this does not work.

Of course, I can create an array of `(list1,list2,score12)` tuples but searching through it given a `list1,list2` pair would be too slow. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Can you post some example data?

Comment: how are you searching values? something like `if val1 in list1 and val2 in list2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dictionary just turning your `list1` and `list2` into tuples (As tupleas are immutable objects they can be keys)

```
dictionary[(tuple(list1), tuple(list2))] = scorevalue(list1, list2)
```

Edit: Apparently hash is not avaible for lists :S

Answer (score 1):

- You can convert your lists to `tuple`s, and then a pair of tuples can be used as a dictionary key.
- You may also try to move this pair of string lists into a separate object of some class (give it a name suitable for your field) and use it as key, but be careful not to spawn new object with the same lists.

---

```
class Key:
    def __init__(self, lst1, lst2):
        self.lst1 = lst1
        self.lst2 = lst2

k = Key([], [])
d = {k: 1}  # d[k] would be fine, but d[Key([], [])] will raise KeyError
```

---

The first approach has a downside - you won't be able to perform list manipulations in-place, since they will be `tuple`s. But while the lists are small enough, performance downgrade is negligible.